# Is it possible to permit a person write permission to a meeting in WebEx / outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365, webex

Outlook in Office 365 version 1701 build 776.2902

...but I think this is essentially a WebEx question.

I'm the leader of the meeting but I can't make it. 
Can I create a meeting such that another person can take over as leader? 
We are using Outlook and WebEx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a while since I used WebEx, but if you logon to WebEx you can designate an alternate host, and they can start your meeting

GoToMeeting has similar functionality, you would designate another user co-organizer.

Skype for Business - I'm not aware of or if you can do this.